# How to ready key and value from firebase db collection

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following db structure in firebase. I want to retrieve this collection and display using ngFor in my view. However I want read Key (which firebase generates when we use push method) of each object to use it later.

[image]

I am retrieving data like this.

```
this.dbref = firebase.database().ref('My top node here');
this.dbref.once('value').then(snapshot => this.myProperty = snapshot.val());
```

if I log myProperty I can see object collection along with Keys like this but I don't know a way to read key associated with each object. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
this.dbref = firebase.database().ref('My top node here');
this.dbref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  this.myProperty = snapshot.val();
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    console.log(child.key, child.val());
  });
})
```